# New York Times Crossword: Is "electrically balanced" in chemistry "apolar" (given), "neutral," or something else entirely?

Tags: terminology

As a lifelong New York Times crossword puzzler, I was baffled by clue 38-Across in today's puzzle (Saturday, May 22, 2021). The solution is a 6-letter word, and the clue is:

> Electrically balanced, in chemistry

The word that comes to my mind is "neutral." The accepted answer is "apolar," a word I've never heard or muttered in my life. I would have gone with "non-polar" long before I hit "apolar," and I'd be in trouble due to the fine print around "non-polar" and "electrically neutral."

The Webster's Third New International Dictionary has this definition for "apolar":

> having no poles - used esp. of nerve cells formerly believed to lack processes

My go-to text for historical chemistry - M. P. Crosland's *Historical Studies in the Language of Chemistry* - yields no answers. From the definition above, it might be something one would encounter in biology, specifically in regards to cellular biology.

Is "apolar" an accepted or commonly-used word in chemistry as a synonym for "electrically neutral," and if so, in what context has this appeared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Apolar* is certainly a valid alternative to *non-polar*.

Either is natural in English as it is for, e.g. "asymptomatic", or its use in chemistry for *non-polar* has been introduced by non native English speakers quickly translating in their works basically the same word, "apolaire" in French and "apolare" in Italian, for instance.
Let me skip this discussion as matter for another SE site.

However, a quick Google chemical oriented search showed me that *apolar* is less diffused than what I expected, and seems to be more recurrent in biochemistry and astrochemistry, or as suggested in a comment, computational chemistry.

For the point more relevant to Chemistry SE,

"1) Is "apolar" an accepted or commonly-used word in chemistry as 2) a synonym for "electrically neutral," and if so, in what context has this appeared?"

For 1) see above. For 2) the answer is NOT. It just means, closer to the general definition that OP has found and reported, that a chemical entity has not (electrical) poles, i.e. no excess or partial electrical charges are present over its part.

While speaking of bonds, or simple biatomic molecules, apolar and non polar means that negligible or no electrical dipole moment is present. Still, an ensemble of *polar* bonds can nevertheless lead, as per vectors summation, to an apolar, or non-polar if you prefere, molecule.

While apolar chemical entities are indeed neutral, the same can be true for very polar uncharged molecules.

Another use of the terms is to classify solvents. In this case partial or overall electrical dipole moments are just one of the many factors influencing the interaction between molecules of different solvents or between them and those of a solute. The interested reader can refer to the section "Other polarity scales" of this Wikipedia article https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvent for more details.

(In the context of the puzzle, the given word definition is somewhat acceptable, because an apolar molecule won't present much of charge whatever finely examined, unless one discerns electrons and nuclei. And the fact that - as for the title rather than the OP text - they gave a somehow vague "electrically balanced" description, makes it quite accurate for apolar, in a crossword.)